# bind property in jquery - identify the Events

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi can someone help me how exactly a bind understands an event passed for example,

```
$("#example_button").bind("click",function(){
    alert("Event is  clicked");
})

$("#example_button").bind("mouseover",function(){
    alert("Event is mouseover");
})
```

How exactly bind figures(identifies) the event.... i mean is there any way to identify a event...

Answer (score 3):

See the [`type` attribute](http://api.jquery.com/event.type/) on the jQuery event object:

```
$("a").click(function(event) {
  alert(event.type); // "click"
});
```

Comment: Here we are saying $("a").click() -> but i don't know about the event it can be click or mouseover